# Type signature needs a type that isn't exported by the library

Tags: haskell, ghc, aeson

So I was using the aeson library, and thought it would be very useful to have the following function:

```
v .:! f = liftM (fromMaybe mempty) (v .:? f)
```

When I ask GHCi for the type, I get:

```
(.:!)
  :: (Monoid r, FromJSON r) =>
     Object
     -> T.Text -> aeson-0.7.0.6:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Parser r
```

However, Parser itself is not actually exported by either `Data.Aeson` or `Data.Aeson.Types`. Am I forced to not have a type signature for the function I have defined?

Alternatively, if anyone knows a better way of accomplishing what I am trying to do, I would be interested in your suggestions.

Comment: [Parser](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.7.0.6/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Parser) is exported from `Data.Aeson.Types`

Comment: Oh... Yep. You are right. I thought I tried that earlier and it didn't work. Must have done something wrong.

Comment: But I guess the question still stands? What would you do if it wasn't?

Comment: @user3217013 From a quick test, it looks like GHC will let you export a function that accepts or returns a type that you don't have access to, and I couldn't figure out a way to specify an explicit type signature when that type is hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present it's entirely possible in Haskell to write code that would have an inferred type that you can't write yourself because of unexported symbols. There was a [discussion about this](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2014-April/022793.html) on the Haskell libraries mailing list in April 2014 where no firm conclusion was reached but the general sense was to keep the current behaviour.

However the general rule is that if a *language extension* would be needed to write the type signature that would be inferred, then you need to enable that extension even if you don't include the signature explicitly.

Comment: Is this because it (sort of) makes sense to export a type synonym without exporting the underlying type?

Comment: Yes, I think that was the argument against. Personally I think it would be better to be complete.

Comment: I believe it's either difficult or impossible to work out whether a type could be expressed in terms of visible synonyms. Whether it actually *does* make sense to export a type synonym while hiding the underlying type is a whole different question; if so, the `pipes` package might be a good place to look for such a thing.

Comment: My position would be that if you export a type synonym you should export the underlying types, and similarly if you export a value you should export all the types in its type.

Comment: I think there should be a compiler warning if a function is exported where its type is inexpressible in other modules.