# Does exporting type constructors make a difference?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have an internal data type, `T a`, that is used in the signature of exported functions:

```
module A (f, g) where

newtype T a = MkT  { unT :: (Int, a) } 
    deriving (Functor, Show, Read) -- for internal use

f :: a -> IO (T a)
f a = fmap (\i -> T (i, a)) randomIO

g :: T a -> a
g = snd . unT
```

What is the effect of not exporting the type constructor `T`? Does it prevent consumers from meddling with values of type `T a`? In other words, is there a difference between the export list `(f, g)` and `(f, g, T())` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prevented

The first thing a consumer will see is that the type doesn't appear in Haddock documentation. In the documentation for `f` and `g`, the type `T`will not be hyperlinked like an exported type. This may prevent a casual reader from discovering `T`'s class instances.

More importantly, a consumer cannot doing anything with `T` at the *type level*. Anything that requires writing a type will be impossible. For instance, a consumer cannot write new class instances involving `T`, or include `T` in a type family. (I don't *think* there's a way around this...)

At the value level, however, the main limitation is that a consumer [cannot write a type annotation including `T`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24684446/1186208):

```
> :t (f . read) :: Read b => String -> IO (A.T b)
<interactive>:1:39: Not in scope: type constructor or class `A.T'
```

### Not prevented

The restriction on type signatures is not as significant a limitation as it appears. The compiler can still *infer* such a type:

```
> :t f . read
f . read :: Read b => String -> IO (A.T b)
```

Any value expression within the inferrable subset of Haskell may therefore be expressed regardless of the availability of the type constructor `T`. If, like me, you're addicted to `ScopedTypeVariables` and extensive annotations, you may be a little surprised by the definition of `unT'` below.

Furthermore, because typeclass instances have global scope, a consumer can use any available class functions without additional limitation. Depending on the classes involved, this may allow significant manipulation of values of the unexposed type. With classes like `Functor`, a consumer can also freely manipulate type parameters, because there's an available function of type `T a -> T b`.

In the example of `T`, deriving `Show` of course exposes the "internal" `Int`, and gives a consumer enough information to hackishly implement `unT`:

```
--  :: (Show a, Read a) => T a -> (Int, a)
unT' = (read . strip . show') `asTypeOf` (mkPair . g)
  where
    strip = reverse . drop 1 . reverse . drop 9

    --   :: T a -> String
    show' = show `asTypeOf` (mkString . g)

    mkPair :: t -> (Int, t)
    mkPair = undefined  
    mkString :: t -> String
    mkString = undefined
```

```
> :t unT'
unT' :: (Show b, Read b) => A.T b -> (Int, b)
> x <- f "x"
> unT' x
(-29353, "x")
```

Implementing `mkT'` with the `Read` instance is left as an exercise.

Deriving something like `Generic` will completely explode any idea of containment, but you'd probably expect that.

### Prevented?

In the corners of Haskell where [type signatures are necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067905/when-are-type-signatures-necessary-in-haskell) or where `asTypeOf`-style tricks don't work, I guess not exporting the type constructor could actually prevent a consumer from doing something they could with the export list `(f, g, T())`.

### Recommendation

Export all type constructors that are used in the type of any value you export. Here, go ahead and include `T()` in your export list. Leaving it out doesn't accomplish anything other than muddying the documentation. If you want to expose an purely abstract immutable type, use a `newtype` with a hidden constructor and no class instances.

Comment: Not exporting the type constructor doesn't allow the user to create "invalid" values, e.g. a non-balanced tree.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn - I'm not sure I understand. Are you thinking of data constructors, like `MkT` in the example?

Comment: Indeed. The fact that it's legal to export a value without also exporting the constructors necessary to express its type is a bit of a wart in the language.